# Notepad++ Undo History wanted

Tags: notepad++, undo, command-history

I cannot seem to find a history in Notepad++ showing you all the actions you did.  Sometimes you might not be sure anymore what the next Undo action would do.

Does this feature really not exist or I just not found it yet?

Comment: You mean you want to see the history? Like 'deleted "text goes here"'? I don't think that feature exists, but npp has an excellent plugin library, so maybe somebody already wrote that, or you could write it yourself...

Comment: I believe OP is looking for an Undo History similar to [Visual Studio's](http://i.imgur.com/AfFsmTr.png)

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ only saves a text file so it's not possible to save meta-data like undo actions. These metadata stay in memory as long it is open.

However, if you select "Verbose backup" in the Preference>Backup menu , Notepad++ will keep timestamped backup copies of the file whenever you save it. This will allow you to access older versions of that file later.